# Do potassium alum and ammonium alum have known negative effects on health?

Tags: hygiene, deodorant

Mineral deodorant seems to be commonly made entirely of [potassium alum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_alum) or [ammonium alum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_aluminium_sulfate) (the latter may always contain 1% or so water). I've found these products extremely effective in preventing body odor. Are these sulfates related to aluminium in any way [which is speculated to increase the risk of breast cancer and Alzheimer’s disease](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/shortcuts/2016/feb/03/dangerous-deodorant-kill-armpit-bacteria-antiperspirants)?